# Get API Key From LinkedIn Issue

Tags: android, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to add new application on linkedIn and getting API and secret key.

from this [createing new application](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer?newapp=)

but while i registering form form for adding new application, i fill all required fields. but after that i faced starange issue every time, it redirects me on main page. and error displaying at header
"There was an unexpected problem that prevented us from completing your request" !!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer after long search, the solution is so strange that:

By giving company name with space, I was not able to create that.
but when I **removed space** from company name, it worked for me and I am succeeded to get my `API key` and `secret key.`

Hope this help others also.

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh, but, its not of any use :-(. linkedIn have completly changed its API, no elder code can work now.... 

http://www.digitaltrends.com/social-media/linkedin-less-friendly-to-developers/

https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

http://thenextweb.com/dd/2015/02/12/linkedin-takes-aim-developers-plans-lock-apis/

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue though my company name had no space.

Product description must be < 50 words. Once I got it under, it worked.